# Definable constructions in o-minimal geometry

Tags: lo.logic, model-theory, definability, o-minimal, algebraic-complexity

Recently I've been working with o-minimal expansions of $(\mathbb{R},\times,+)$, and I want to work "internally" to the language of o-minimal sets instead of working with "definable families".

This is for a simple practical reason: I can't explain ANYTHING in the definable family formalism to my combinatorialist colleagues, since they haven't had the luxury of being fully saturated in the Yoneda-lemma style Grothendieckian constructions certain (algebraic) geometers have become accustomed to.

However I've had great success with an alternate formalism.

Some natural constructions seem to "escape" this formalism, so I break the formalism in a consistent way to accommodate these constructions, making me think there's a formalism which encompasses what I'm doing. This seems like something that might be standard in model theory, and I am wondering if anyone can help.

The questions are at the end after some background.

**Current Setup: Complexity Formalism**

I have a finite collection of functions $f_1,\ldots,f_r$ of various arities $f_i:\mathbb{R}^{e_i}\to \mathbb{R}$, and I'm supposing that they generate an o-minimal structure, meaning that any first order formula with one free variable involving these functions and $+,\times$ defines a subset of $\mathbb{R}$ which is a finite union of points and intervals.

A definable set $S_\phi\subset \mathbb{R}^d$ is defined by a first order formula $\phi$ with $d$ free variables.

Say that the "complexity" of a formula $\phi$ is the number of symbols used in its definition (with real constants counting as 1 symbol).

I want to work with the notion of complexity in place of where theorems would typically generalize via "definable families", replacing $A\subset \mathbb{R}^n$ with a statement about the fibers of a map $\mathbb{R}^n\times \mathbb{R}^m\to \mathbb{R}^m$. (I don't forbid that definable families appear in constructions, just in the main use cases for extending theorems from single definable sets to families of definable sets).

**Example comparing formalisms**

Let's consider a simple example: A definable subset $A\subset \mathbb{R}^n$ has finitely many connected components. We want to generalize this to statements about how the number of connected components varies with $A$.

In the definable families formalism, this is generalized to say that if we have a subset $A'\subset \mathbb{R}^n\times \mathbb{R}^m$, then the number of components of the fibers of $\pi\times id|_{A'}$ are uniformly bounded.

In the complexity formalism, this is generalized to say that the number of connected components of $A$ is bounded in terms of the complexity of $A$.

These are actually completely equivalent: In one direction, the fibers of $\pi\times id|_{A'}$ are of bounded complexity in terms of $A'$ since the fiber over $x$ is obtained by intersecting $A'$ with $\mathbb{R}^n\times \{x\}$. In the other direction, for a fixed formula type (say two formulas have the same type if they only differ in the real constants used) take the "universal family" for that formula type, where $\mathbb{R}^m$ parametrizes all possible values of these $m$ constants. Then since there were only finitely many functions $f_1,\ldots,f_r$, there are only finitely many formula types of a given complexity.

Although they're equivalent, as long as I start with a definable set and only do "allowed" things to it, I'm always guaranteed to have bounded complexity. This means I can bound my quantities at the end of a proof in terms of the inputs at the beginning, without needing to drag along auxilliary definable families throughout.

**Problem**

After taking basic theorems in o-minimal geometry and phrasing them in terms of complexity, 99% of the time I can work without even knowing that my sets are o-minimal, and at my leisure I can access the "bounded complexity" oracle to plug into some theorem like the one above to get that some geometric quantity is bounded whenever I want.

However, although this might be fine to access the oracle to get natural numbers occasionally (breaking the abstraction slightly), I keep stumbling with theorems such as "Given a map $f:A\to B$, the set $\{x\in B:\dim f^{-1}(x)=k\}$ is a definable subset of $B$ of bounded complexity."

If I have two linear maps $f,g:A\to \mathbb{R}^n$ and the set
\begin{align}
\big\{x\in \mathbb{R}^n:\ &\dim f^{-1}(x)=k\text{ and }\\ &\big(\text{# of connected components of }g^{-1}(x)\big)=\ell\big\},
\end{align}
then I can apply the above two theorems in succession to bound the set's complexity in terms of $A$. But this process was not automatic --- I couldn't just use the fact that the formula was syntactically correct to deduce the conclusion.

**Questions**

Let $\mathcal{D}(\mathbb{R}^n)$ be the definable subsets of $\mathbb{R}^n$.

Consider the second order functions
\begin{align}
\text{complexity}&:\ \mathcal{D}(\mathbb{R}^n)\to \mathbb{N}\\
\dim&:\ \mathcal{D}(\mathbb{R}^n)\to \mathbb{N}\\
\#\text{ of connected components}&:\ \mathcal{D}(\mathbb{R}^n)\to \mathbb{N}\\
\end{align}
Consider also the constructions
\begin{align}
i^{th}\text{ simplex in a definable triangulation}&:\ \mathcal{D}(\mathbb{R}^n)\to \mathcal{D}(\mathbb{R}^n)\\
f^{-1}&:\ \phantom{\mathcal{D}(}\mathbb{R}^m\to \mathcal{D}(\mathbb{R}^n)
\end{align}
where $f$ is a definable function from $\mathbb{R}^n\to \mathbb{R}^m$.

My questions are:

- Is there a metatheorem that any formula
  $$\Phi:\mathcal{D}(\mathbb{R}^n)\to \mathcal{P}(\mathbb{R}^n)$$
  will always produce definable sets if it
  combines these second-order functions and constructions with the usual first-order syntax for the $o$-minimal structure in a syntactically correct way?
- Is there a metatheorem that any similarly constructed formula
  $$\Phi':\mathcal{D}(\mathbb{R}^n)\to \mathbb{N}$$
  has an output bounded by a function of the input's complexity?
- What axioms would further constructions have to satisfy for these metatheorems to hold?

Comment: A couple comments: First, I'm a bit surprised that combinatorists have issues with definable families of sets. A definable family of sets is in particular a set system, and I thought they know about set systems. Secondly, I have seen this kind of complexity approach in the semialgebraic setting - in that setting you have quantifier elimination so the definition is simpler. For example, there is a book by Yomdin and Comte on tame geometry that proves a lot of things about semialgebraic sets of bounded complexity. Finally, I haven't seen a theorem of the sort you are looking for, and I doubt

Comment: hat anyone has proven such a result in the o-minimal setting. But I think that you are essentially describing a common method (maybe what people call a "yoga"), but I don't think it's been formalized to the extent that you want

Comment: I do agree that this is a very good way to try to explain stuff to the kind of mathematicians who love to bound things in terms of other things.

Comment: @ErikWalsberg Unnecessary parameter spaces is an actual problem not just for combinatorialists, because geometric constructions often don't have the intended interpretation of "constructions for families", creating a genuine barrier to understanding statements and proofs (and notating multiple projections consistently is a nightmare). We don't invoke the Hilbert scheme every time we talk about degree d curves, or explicitly extend measure spaces in every day probability theory. In Computer Science I think they have Monads for computational contexts which handle side effects behind the scenes?

Comment: I'm always amazed at the lengths people will go to to avoid explicitly using formulas of first-order logic. Thinking about a definable set as being defined by a formula with parameters and then thinking about what happens when you vary the parameters is far more elementary than "Yoneda-lemma style Grothendieckian constructions" and I would argue that it's also conceptually simpler than thinking about bounds in terms of complexity (though I agree with you and Erik that for psychological reasons it can be useful to have multiple ways to present the same idea, depending on your audience).

Comment: @AlexKruckman Sure, so logicians have "parametrised formulas", where you write something like $\phi(x_1,\ldots,x_n;y_1,\ldots,y_m)$ and the $y_i$'s are unbound parameters, which solves the problem that you have to "know" that $\pi\times id_A$ is about a parametrized family to extract the intended meaning (since with this syntax the parameter variables have a special flavor). My question can be asked in this context too: What is $\dim$? If I use these kinds of "second-order" constructions consistently then can I always simplify to a parametrized formula? What are the rules I have to follow?

Comment: It seems like there are two issues here. (1) The issue of "uniform definability in families": Given some property $P$ of definable sets and some formula $\varphi(x;y)$, is there a formula $\psi_{\varphi,P}(y)$ such that the set defined by $\varphi(x;b)$ satisfies $P$ if and only if $\psi_{\varphi,P}(b)$ is true? Here $P$ can be something like "has dimension $k$". You can do something similar for constructions that assign definable sets to definable sets. The uniform definability of $P$ in families depends on $P$, and there is no "automatic" way to check this.

Comment: (2) GIven some properties/constructions that are uniformly definable in families, in what ways can we combine them to get new properties that are uniformly definable in families? Well, the most answer to this is "by the rules for building first-order formulas". It could be possible to translate the syntactic rules for formula-building into conditions that don't mention formulas, but usually such translations end up being quite awkward. Have I understood your question correctly? If so, I'm happy to expand these comments into an answer if you think they're useful.

Comment: In 3-d (with $\mathbf{uvwxy}$ as 3-d vectors and $hrst$ as reals in $[0,1]$), we can consider $\text{dim}$ an informal abbreviation for the expressions
$$\text{dim}(\{\mathbf{x}:\phi(\mathbf{x,y})\})\ge \begin{cases}3\\2\\1\\0\end{cases}$$
which are formally defined as
$$(\exists\mathbf{u}\,\exists \text{ linearly independent} \mathbf{vwx}\,\forall r s t\,\exists h)
\\
(\left\{
\begin{array}{r}
h=t\,\wedge\\
0<t\to h<t\,\wedge\\
s=0<t\to h<t\,\wedge\\
r=s=0\to \phantom{h=t\,\wedge}\\
\end{array}
\right\} \phi(\mathbf{u}+r\mathbf{v}+s\mathbf{w}+h\mathbf{x,y}))$$

Comment: @MattF. I'm not sure that the expression you wrote represents the o-minimal dim, but you make a good point dim might be easier to handle because it can never be larger than the dimension of the ambient space (so represent it with the propositions $\dim_k$ for $k\le n$ that the set is of dimension $k$). I think # of connected components is the more confusing one --- even # of connected components just in $\mathbb{R}^1$ could be arbitrarily large, so I can't represent it with the same trick as with $\dim$.

Comment: In 1-d, $\{r: \phi(r,s)\}$ has at most $1+\sum\deg(f)$ components, where $f$ ranges over polynomials appearing in $\phi$. So we can count the components in a reasonably first-order way. The 2-d case is worse: $\{(r,s): \phi(r,s)\}$ has disconnected components iff some bivariate polynomial $g$ satisfies
$$\exists tuvw\,\forall xy\, \phi(t,u) \wedge \phi(v,w) \wedge g(t,u)>0 \wedge g(v,w)<0 \wedge (g(x,y)=0 \to \neg\phi(x,y))$$
But a good first-order definition for disconnected components in $\mathbb{R}^2$ requires a good bound on $\deg(g)$ in terms of degrees in $\phi$, and I have neither.

Comment: @MattF. Your reference to "polynomials appearing in $\phi$" in your last comment makes me think you're only considering the case of real closed fields, while the question is about general o-minimal expansions of the real field.

Comment: @AlexKruckman, we could probably generalize from real-closed fields, e.g. by defining a degree of a Pfaffian function using the polynomials in its Pfaffian chain.

Comment: @AlexKruckman Yeah, in general I think people often don't want to accept the model-theoretic approach. Like when I gave talks on motivitic integration to algebraists it took a some effort to convince them that a definable set is just a literal subset of $M^n$ and that a definable function is just a function whose graph is definable.

Comment: I also think that the complexity viewpoint is particularly interesting when you can get explicit bounds in terms of the complexity. For example Khovanskii gave explicit bounds on the number of connected components of a Pfaffian set in terms of the complexity (this is called "fewnomials".) This work is what motivated the initial development of o-minimality - Lou goes to Khovanskii's talk at the ICM, realizes that Khovanskii had shown that any quantifier free R_exp definable set has finitely many connected components, and starts to wonder if that could generalize to all R_exp definable sets.

Comment: I think you will find a lot of answers in this new preprint https://arxiv.org/abs/2209.10972. Following the ICM talk by Binyamini and Novikov, Together with Zack they introduce a notion of Sharply o-minimal structures, strongly axiomatizing the notion of complexity in o-minimal structures. Firstly, not all o-minimal structures can support a notion of complexity. Secondly, your notion of complexity unfortunately seems too weak for applications, because connected components of $X$ tend to grow exponentially (or even doubly exponentially) in terms of the length of the formula describing $X$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will expand my comment into at least a partial (but for me quite illuminating answer). As I’ve mentioned in the comments, the question of complexity in o-minimality was recently adressed in an ICM talk by Gal Binyamini and Dmitri Novikov, and then formally introduced together with Benny Zack in the following preprint https://arxiv.org/abs/2209.10972.

Unfortuantely, it is impossible to control connected components using your notion of complexity. As far as I understand, this is because $\mathbb{R}_{an}$ is too big (In the words of a renowned expert who shall remain anonymous “$\mathbb{R}_{an}$ is a POC”) , and you can’t control say the zeros of an analytic function, in general. See the example in section 1.4.2 from the attached preprint for more details. Another problem is that even if you manage to get bounds in terms of the OP’s suggested complexity, it will be exponential or even doubly exponential, even in important structures coming from geometry, making it problematic at least for a certain range of applications.

Notable exeptions are the semialgebraic structure and the various Pfaffian structures, where you have two parameters controlling complexity - “format” and “degree”. For a semialgebraic set, the format is its ambient dimension, and its degree is the sum of the degrees of a system defining the set. For (sub) Pfaffian sets the definition is similar. And in general, format is very similar to the definition you gave for complexity. It is important to distinguish between format and degree, as typically bounds on connected components (such as in the work of Khovanskii) are exponentiall or even doubly exponential in the format, but polynomial in the degree.

Actually, the above two structures are the only known examples of “sharply o-minimal structures”, o-minimal structures satisfying the axioms put forward by Binyamini, Novikov and Zack. In these axioms, definable sets have format and degree, and there are axioms about the format and degree of various (logical) set-theoretic operations. Additionally, there is an axiom saying that if a definable subset of the line has format F and degree D, then it has $poly_{F}(D)$ connected components. From this (and some other things) I believe they answer all of your questions (they have a section about triangulations), at least in the context of sharply o-minimal structures.